# Array to String Error in Mysql using PHP

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I have an Android application that sends a Json as a string to the server in PHP. I've tested with var_dump to verify that the data was being passed correctly and everything is ok. The problem is that when I try to access json and assign values from a nested array of the main object to an array in PHP, I got an error when I try to include this array in Mysql. I've tested only PHP and MySQL and everything is working perfectly.

```
if  (!empty($_POST)){
   $info = file_get_contents('php://input');
   $json = json_decode($info, true);
   $login= "";
   $useExercise = array();
  //var_dump($info);

   foreach($json['Patient'][0] as $name){
      $login = $name;
   }


   foreach ($json['Patient'][1]as $exercise){
       $useExercise[] = array($exercise);
   }

for ($i=0; sizeOf($useExercise) > $i; $i++){

    $exercicies= mysqli_fetch_array($order);
    $sql1 = ("UPDATE patient_exercise
             INNER JOIN patients ON (patient_exercise.idpatient =  patients.ID)
             INNER JOIN exercises ON (exercises.idexercises  = patient_exercise.idexercise)
             SET patient_exercise.use_exercise=$useExercise[$i]     
             WHERE patient_exercise.idexercise= {$exercises['idexercise']} AND
                   patients.ID=(SELECT c.ID FROM (SELECT * FROM patients ) as c 
                                 WHERE c.login_patients  = '$login');");

    mysqli_query($connect, $sql1);


   }
}
```

the error occurs on `SET patient_exercise.use_exercise=$useExercise[$i]`

And my Json is:

```
{"Paciente":[{"Nome":"Rafael"},
           {"Exercicios":[{"0":"1"},
                        {"1":"0"},
                        {"2":"0"}]}]
}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

So, I've made a mistake by not capturing the data from `$json` properly. I've also changed my json object.
What I did was this:

```
 $result= array();
    foreach($json as $patients){
        foreach ($patients as $key=>$value){
            foreach ($value as $a=>$b)          
                    $result[] = $b;     
        }       
    }

    for ($i=0; sizeOf($result)>$i;$i++){
        if($i ==0){
            $login = $result[$i];
        } 
        else{
            $useExercise[]=$result[$i];
        }
    }
```

And my modified Json:

```
{"patient":[{"name":"rafael"},
             {"0":"1","1":"0","2":"0"}
            ]
}
```

Thank you, Kingsley Mitchell for taking your time to help me! :)

Comment: Sorry. I just did it! :D

Answer (score 0):

Think your main problem is you are making it to complex by jumping steps instead of doing it step by step.

Make it simple because it looks confusing and it is hard to correct because your context and naming conventions are not easy to understand.

Try this format :  `$SQL = "UPDATE isignup SET password='". $NPass ."' WHERE custID='$num'";`

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question. What steps could I add so you can understand it better?

Comment: You are updating multiple rows in a database at once, try splitting it up into one-liners .

Comment: Joins are notorious of problems

Comment: Take out the joins and make it without the joins first.

Comment: But Im using a FOR. How am I adding multiple rows at once? 
I'm using each element from an array and adding each one of them at a time. At least from what I understand from the FOR clause.

Comment: SET patient_exercise.use_exercise=$useExercise[$i]

also there may be a problems with this statement because php is very finiky with "" or '' when introducing varibles from php into mysql statements.

try this format: $SQL = "UPDATE isignup SET password='". $NPass ."' WHERE custID='$num'";

Comment: That's exactly my problem. I get an error from this statement.

Comment: Yeah because you are passing information incorrectly. It is an easy mistake and no 1 really knows.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it also.

Comment: *Off Topic*: I see that you live in Melbourne and that's such a nice city to live. Spent in there 1 year and I can't wait to go back! Love Melbs! :)

Comment: Haha yeah not to bad  :)

Comment: Feel free to add me on linkedin

Comment: Ok.. I'll.. Also, It might take some time for me to properly test it cause I'm testing with my Android App. Send some news soon.. Managed to get rid of some problems but this one is really annoying.

Comment: So, I've tested it and I still get the same Array to String Error. I've modified to 
SET patient_exercise.use_exercise='" . $useExercise[$i] . "' on my code

Comment: $json = file_get_contents('url_here');
$obj = json_decode($json);
echo $obj->access_token;

Comment: Think you may have something wrong with the info going into that array then

Comment: So I'm using a Web Service to send the data from the app to the PHP file via POST. The output is a table from the error that I get from the PHP file.. And in that error I got this: (!) </span> Notice: Array to String conversion in C:\wamp64\www\Fisioapp\save_user.php on line <i> 101</i>

Comment: Ahh because previously you are not turning the varibles String into the array properly. Getting closer.

Comment: Output the array first to check print_r();

Comment: foreach ($json['Patient'][1]as $exercise){
       $useExercise[] = array($exercise);
   } 
I have never seen this format before

Comment: Well... I was trying to find how to get an object content from the json and it worked..

Comment: I'll test with var_dump again and also with print_r()

Comment: I just used print_r and it prints my json object correctly.. Jezz.. As you can see I'm kinda new to programming and it's really nice to see everything working, but when you get stuck into something and you can't get rid of the problem is so frustrating.

Comment: $useExercise[$i]  set this as a static

Comment: I've done this {static $useExercise = array();} and still got the same error.

Comment: I've tested the $useExercise[] from the foreach and apparently this is not working. How would get the value from the array [{"0":"1"},
                        {"1":"0"},
                        {"2":"0"}]}]?